# Image not fitting into image view after cropping

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to crop an image. When the below code is executed, the image is cropped and only a part of it is shown in the image view. The image becomes bigger than the image view. I want to crop the image and fit it perfectly in the image view.

```
  CGImageRef imageRef1 = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], star1Rect);
                    UIImage *croppedImage1 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef1];
                    CGImageRelease(imageRef1);
                    cell.ImageView.frame=star1Rect;
                    cell.ImageView.image=nil;
                    cell.ImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                    cell.ImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
                    cell.ImageView.image=croppedImage1;
```

This is the output I'm getting -  https://www.dropbox.com/s/b70xzi9g5rc0y8u/rsz_1ios_simulator_screen_shot_mar_27_2015_25749_pm.png?dl=0

Comment: Can you link some screenshots of the original image, the result image and the display in the image view

Comment: Drop a break point on croppedImage1 image and check image exist or not.

Comment: croppedImage1 is having content. I tried setting break point.

Comment: Wain, I have added the link to the screenshot image.

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
cell.ImageView.contentMode   = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
cell.ImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is resizing your imageView to the size of the cropped image:

```
cell.ImageView.frame=star1Rect;
```

You should get rid of it in order to maintain the original size of the image view, and let:

```
cell.ImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

do the resize of the cropped image to fit your imageView original size.

Comment: I'm getting the same output.

Comment: It is impossible you have the same output because you are changing the frame of your imageView, so at least that size is different. In the other hand: the image you have uploaded is the cropped one? Can you post the original one?

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
cell.ImageView.contentMode   = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
cell.ImageView.layer.masksToBounds = TRUE;
```